# Sum value for element in PHP

Tags: php

I have data like below. I have to sum up each month value for each element starting July until current month or any month based on user selection. I don't know if i should use for or while looping in PHP.
Hope someone can point me to the right direction.

```
Element | Jan | Feb | Mar |Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dis
==============================================================================
A       | 78  | 65  | 44   |67 | 76  | 88  | 66  | 65  | 87  | 90  | 56  | 70
B       | 78  | 65  | 44   |67 | 76  | 88  | 66  | 65  | 87  | 90  | 56  | 70
C       | 78  | 65  | 44   |67 | 76  | 88  | 66  | 65  | 87  | 90  | 56  | 70
```

Query

```
$sql2 = "Select element,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 'Jan' THEN total ELSE 0 END ) AS Jan,
SUM(CASE WHEN Month = 'Feb' THEN total ELSE 0 END ) AS Feb  //until Dec
FROMtbl_ma GROUP BY element";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$getRec2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2);
```

Print

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs2)) {    
echo $row['Jan'] //until Dec
}
```

Comment: May I know, In which formation of array you have this data ?

Comment: @LalitSharma what do you mean? I'm sorry , i'm really new to PHP.

Comment: How you have print this data pls share that code with us !

Comment: Can you share the code used to produce the data you have here?

Comment: @LalitSharma  I add the query and how i print in the question

Comment: Please edit your question and put that query there !

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest would be to use the

```
array_sum()
```

function, which will add up all the values in an array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php